# How can I include a ".mustache" file in erlang release?

Tags: erlang, rebar, relx

I am trying to use the [mustache](https://github.com/mojombo/mustache.erl) erlang lib with the separate template and view. I am using the rebar3 release structure.

I follow the example in the docs, if I create both the `simple.erl` and `simple.mustache`. However, when I perform `rebar3 compile`, my final ebin directory only includes the `simple.beam`.

How can I make sure the compile/release process bundles the `simple.mustache` file?

Here is the layout of my apps:

[image]

Here is my rebar.config:

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, [
    {cowboy, {git, "git://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git", {tag, "1.0.1"}}},
  {mustache, {git, "git@github.com:mojombo/mustache.erl.git", {tag, "v0.1.1"}}}
]}.

{relx, [{release, { kitty, "0.1.0" },
         [kitty,
          kitty_api,
          sasl]},

        {sys_config, "./config/sys.config"},
        {vm_args, "./config/vm.args"},

        {dev_mode, true},
        {include_erts, false},

        {extended_start_script, true}]
}.

{profiles, [{prod, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                            {include_erts, true}]}]
            }]
}.
```

Here is my `kitty_api_app.src`, which contains the `simple.mustache` in it's `src` dir:

```
{application, kitty_api,
 [{description, "Kitty HTTP API"},
  {vsn, "0.1.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {mod, { kitty_api_app, []}},
  {applications,
   [kernel,
    stdlib,
    kitty,
    cowboy
   ]},
  {env,[]},
  {modules, []},

  {maintainers, []},
  {licenses, []},
  {links, []}
 ]}.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Erlang/OTP Application Perspective

According to the [Directory Structure](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id75737) chapter in the OTP Design Principles an Erlang application consists of the following subdirectories:

> src - Contains the Erlang source code.
>   ebin - Contains the Erlang object code, the beam files. The .app file is also placed here.
>   **priv - Used for application specific files. For example, C executables 
>   are placed here. The function code:priv_dir/1 is to be used to access this directory.**
>   include - Used for include files

In face that, it's not appropriate to put files that are not the source code to the `src/` directory. priv/ is the right place to put them in.

### Rebar3 perspective

[The documentation of compile command in rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/commands#compile) says:

> After ensuring all dependencies are available, (...) compile will compile the needed depdendencies and the **project's apps .app.src and .erl files**.

Which compiles with the OTP desing principles. As your mustache file that sits in the `src/` is neither an `.app.src` file nor .erl file, rebar is doing nothing with it.

### Erlang/OTP Release perspetive

And finally, the aforementioned OTP document says this about Erlang releases:

> The directory structure for the code installed by the release handler from a release package is as follows:

```
$ROOT/lib/App1-AVsn1/ebin  
                    /priv  
        /App2-AVsn2/ebin
                   /priv
        ...
       /AppN-AVsnN/ebin
                  /priv
       /erts-EVsn/bin
       /releases/Vsn
       /bin
```

As you can see, only `ebin/` and `priv/` are expected to be placed in an application that is a part of a release - so leaving your `.mustache` file in the `src/` is not an option.

### Conclusion

The `.mustache` files should be treated as application specific files and thus be put in the application `priv/` directory. If placed in the `src/`, rebar won't copy them to the `ebin/`. When building a release, the applications that it is made up of are copied along with their `priv` directories.

Comment: So the `priv/blah.mustache` would be available under `code:priv_name(myapp)`? http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1

Comment: Yeahs, try this: `code:priv_dir(mustache).` or `code:priv_dir(cowboy).`

Comment: Yes. That should work in your release. But be aware that if you start your system out of release, like `erl -pa ebin/` then it won't work. In that case you have to provide the code path as `erl -pa ../YOUR_APP/ebin`.

Answer (score 2):

Only `beam` files and the `app`/`appup` file should be really in the `ebin` folder. Can you place the `.mustache` file in the `priv` folder? Folder `priv` should be copied automatically. Unless it's expected that the `.mustache` file should be compiled to an `.erl` file and then to a `beam` file as it is the case with some other Erlang-related source files that are not exactly `.erl` files. I don't know much about the `mustache` port for Erlang but it looks like it's trying to do something in a non-standard way, that might not be portable across systems and release tools.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `mustache` lib expects it to be available in the root dir somehow...

Comment: Check if the path where is the file is in code root: `rp(code:get_path()).` if not then add it with `code:add_path/1` http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#add_path-1